# Nativescript on MacOS - cannot add platform android to project

Tags: android, nativescript

When i do "tns platform add android" i always get the error message "You need to have the Android SDK Build-tools installed on your system. You can install any version in the following range: '>=25.0.2'." The correct SDK build tools are installed.

[android sdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFAx9.png)

Can anybody help me?

Comment: If you run `tns doctor`, do you see any problems reported related to missing Android SDK tools?

Comment: I run tns doctor, the ANDROID_HOME variable was incorrect. Fixed this and did a restart, now everything works - THX!